# angular pagination directive not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, pagination

I've created a directive for pagination that will work with grids across the site. On this page I have a search which will return a new set of data, and I want to pass that data into my directive so it then has a new pagination. At the moment I only have a link function.

**directive html**

```
<table-pagination current-page="1" num-per-page="5" max-size="5" pagination-data="membersData" get-filtered-data="getFilteredData(membersData)" returned-paginated-data="returnedPaginatedData(data)"></table-pagination>
```

**directive.js**

```
myAppModule.directive('tablePagination',
        function () {
            return {
                templateUrl: 'Scripts/app/templates/tmplPagination.html',
                restrict: 'E',
                scope: {
                    currentPage: '=',
                    numPerPage: '=',
                    maxSize: '=',
                    paginationData: '=',
                    getFilteredData: '=',
                    filteredMembersData: '&'
                },
                link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
                    scope.getFilteredData = function () {
                        $scope.$watch('currentPage + numPerPage', function () {
                            var begin = (($scope.currentPage - 1) * $scope.numPerPage), end = begin + $scope.numPerPage;
                            $scope.filteredMembersData = scope.paginationData.slice(begin, end);
                        });
                    }
                },
                controller: [
                '$scope', function ($scope) {

                }]
            }
        });
```

**pagination template**

```
<h4>Total number of records: {{membersData.length}}</h4>
<pagination ng-model="currentPage" total-items="membersData.length" max-size="maxSize"  boundary-links="true"></pagination>
```

**Contact search controller**

```
$scope.returnedPaginatedData = function(data) {
                $scope.filteredMembersData = data;
            }
```

I want to pass in  $scope.filteredMembersData into my directive so it re-renders my pagination.

Any ideas how to get this working?

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution:

**Directive HTML**

```
 <table-pagination current-page="1" num-per-page="5" max-size="5" source-data="membersData" grid-data="gridData"></table-pagination>
```

I pass in some settings for how the grid looks and the data source (whole data). I also pass in an array (gridData)

**Directive.js**

```
myAppModule.directive('tablePagination',
        function () {
            return {
                templateUrl: 'Scripts/app/templates/tmplPagination.html',
                restrict: 'E',
                scope: {
                    currentPage: '=',
                    numPerPage: '=',
                    maxSize: '=',
                    sourceData: '=',
                    gridData: '='
                },
                link: function (scope, elem, attrs) { // need this for when pagination is clicked
                        scope.$watch('currentPage + numPerPage', function () {
                            var begin = ((scope.currentPage - 1) * scope.numPerPage), end = begin + scope.numPerPage;
                            scope.gridData = scope.sourceData.slice(begin, end);
                        });

                },
                controller: [
                '$scope', function ($scope) {
                    $scope.$watch('sourceData', function () { // need this for when data changes
                        var begin = (($scope.currentPage - 1) * $scope.numPerPage), end = begin + $scope.numPerPage;
                        $scope.gridData = $scope.sourceData.slice(begin, end);
                    });

                }]
            }
        });
```

I have a watch for when the data changes and another for current page and number page. These act as event handles when I click the pagination to go to the next set of data.

**template.html**

```
<div>
    <h4>Total number of records: {{sourceData.length}}</h4>
    <pagination ng-model="currentPage" total-items="sourceData.length" max-size="maxSize" boundary-links="true"></pagination> 
</div>
```

I have some pagination html here to configure it.

I'm able to plug this into any grid on my site, I just need some data and empty array for the set of the data to display in the grid.